# Core data error - 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -objCType only defined for abstract class. Define -[FormatNumber objCType]!'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

I'm getting this error when using my app. It's a simple calculator and it happens when I press a number:

```
2013-01-12 21:13:32.175 Basic Calc[1683:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '***
-objCType only defined for abstract class.  Define -[FormatNumber objCType]!'
*** First throw call stack: (0x1c8f012 0x10cce7e 0x1c8edeb 0xb96f35 0xba6b3f 0xb1a049 0xac8fc5 0x1c09ac6 0x1c4f13c 0xac8f60 0xac8eab 0x2b4b 0x10e0705 0x17920 0x178b8 0xd8671 0xd8bcf 0xd7872 0x4716d 0x47552 0x253aa 0x16cf8 0x1beadf9 0x1beaad0 0x1c04bf5 0x1c04962 0x1c35bb6 0x1c34f44 0x1c34e1b 0x1be97e3 0x1be9668 0x1465c 0x27cd 0x26f5) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Here it is part of my code:

MainViewController.m

```
currentNumber = currentNumber *10 + (float)[sender tag]; 
FormatNumber *convertedNumber;
convertedNumber = [[FormatNumber alloc] init];
[convertedNumber getNumber:currentNumber];
calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",convertedNumber];
```

FormatNumber.m

```
@interface FormatNumber: NSNumber
{
    NSString *nf;
}

-(NSString *) getNumber:(float)n1;

@end
```

FormatNumber.m

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
nf = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: n1]];
return nf;
```

Also, when I got the error the code points to this line in main.m:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Any ideas?

---

New code:

MainViewController.h

```
currentNumber = currentNumber *10 + (float)[sender tag];
NSNumber *convertedNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
NSString *finalValue = [convertedNumber customFormatNumber:currentNumber];
calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",finalValue];
```

NSNumber+FormatNumber.h

```
@interface NSNumber (FormatNumber)
-(NSString *) customFormatNumber:(float)n1;
@end
```

NSNumber+FormatNumber.m

```
@implementation NSNumber(FormatNumber)
-(NSString *) customFormatNumber:(float)n1
{
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
        [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
        NSString *nf = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:n1]];
        return nf;
```

Comment: Why do you think this is a Core Data error ?

Comment: Do not ever subclass umbrella classes or class clusters without overriding every exposed method.

Comment: I made a confusion about the Core Data error, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is Core Data problem.

Try avoiding subclassing NSNumber and use category instead.

You can look [**here**](http://cupsofcocoa.com/2011/03/27/objective-c-lesson-8-categories/) for example

Comment: Tried it as @CarlVeazey explained below, but couldn't get it to work yet. Maybe I'm missing something when calling it :( (see my comment below if possible)

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Core Data. You've subclassed `NSNumber` but haven't followed the rules laid out in the [NSNumber documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> As with any class cluster, if you create a subclass of NSNumber, you
>   have to override the primitive methods of its superclass, NSValue.
>   Furthermore, there is a restricted set of return values that your
>   implementation of the NSValue method objCType can return, in order to
>   take advantage of the abstract implementations of the non-primitive
>   methods. The valid return values are “c”, “C”, “s”, “S”, “i”, “I”,
>   “l”, “L”, “q”, “Q”, “f”, and “d”.

If the only reason you've subclassed is to implement that `getNumber:` method, you should use an Objective-C Category instead.

In `NSNumber+MyCategoryName.h`:

```
@interface NSNumber (MyCategoryName)

- (NSString *)getNumberAsString:(float)n1;

@end
```

In `NSNumber+MyCategoryName.m`

```
@implementation NSNumber (MyCategoryName)

- (NSString *)getNumberAsString:(float)n1
{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
    NSString *nf = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: n1]];
    return nf;
}

@end
```

However, I don't think it's a good idea to put this method as a category on `NSNumber`. I could see it being a class method on `NSNumberFormatter`, perhaps. Finally, it's against the naming rules to call this method `getNumber:`; methods that start with `get` are usually reserved for methods that return multiple values through references passed in as arguments. Perhaps a better name would be `-max2FractionDigits:`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But I couldn't get it to work yet :(      in NSNumber+MyCategoryName.m `return nf;` is getting **Incompatible pointer types returning 'NSString *__strong' from a function with result type 'NSNumber *'***. Also, I don't know if I'm calling it right from the MainViewController.m:  `convertedNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] init];  [convertedNumber customFormatNumber:currentNumber];  calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",convertedNumber];` Any help here?

Comment: @Adami I had copied over your code and missed the return type bug, I corrected the return type of the method in my code.

Comment: Thanks again, but I have one more question: the variable that will get the value from the return must be a NSNumber type, right? I tried to call `getNumberAsString` class with `convertedNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] init];  [convertedNumber getNumberAsString:currentNumber];` but it's breaking in the last line :( (convertedNumber is declared as NSNumber and should get the `return nf;`, currentNumber has the value to be converted)

Comment: @Adami Wait, what? Do you want an `NSString` or an `NSNumber`?

Comment: Sorry, it's NSString since this is what returning is giving back and I've just changed the variable to NSString. But, is this right `[convertedNumber getNumberAsString:currentNumber];`? It's giving me this error in this line `No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'getNumberAsString:'`

Comment: In your code `convertedNumber` is declared as `FormatNumber`, did you change something to declare it as a string?

Comment: Yes, it's declared as string. I've just added in the first post how my code is now.

Comment: And I've used in my previous posts your `getNumberAsString` name but in my code I'm using `convertFormatNumber`.

Comment: @Adami You're sending a message to an `NSString` that you've declared to be on `NSNumber`.

Comment: I didn't get it, should I change `NSString *convertedNumber = [[NSString alloc] init];` to `NSNumber *convertedNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] init];`?

Comment: @Adami yes, and you'll need a string variable to store the return value of the method.

Comment: Yes, I saw that and I was thinking about it but my VM just crashed :( How that should be? The method is returning `nf` that is already a string but is set to `convertedNumber` that is a NSNumber. Should `NSString *finalValue = [convertedNumber customFormatNumber:currentNumber];` be enough to work? It's late here and I'm going to sleep, thanks a lot for today!

Comment: Now it's crashing on `calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",convertedNumber];` line :( Do you know what is wrong here?

Comment: @Adami what does the console say when it crashes? maybe there's a clue there.

Comment: Forget about the crashing, the problem is that is printing (null), something before is wrong yet :/

Comment: I added some breakpoints and NSLog messages but I couldn't see the method being executed, maybe it's not being called correctly?